# Bootstrap navbar dropdown problem on angular

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, angular-bootstrap

I'm having problems with the bootstrap navbar on Angular, I can't get the dropdown menu to load. The bootstrap scripts are linked in the angular.json file, I really can't figure out why. On an online editor the same code works fine. I attach the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="../../../assets/images/logo.png" style="width: 100px;" alt="logo">
      </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" routerLink="/">
          <span class="material-icons md-home" title="home" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" title="Prod"  routerLink="/art">
          <span class="material-icons md-archive" title="prodotti" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Prod
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" title="Promo" routerLink="/promo">
          <span class="material-icons md-campaign" title="promozioni" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Promo
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" title="Fidelity" routerLink="/fidelity">
          <span class="material-icons md-card_membership" title="Fidelity" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Fidelity
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" title="Ord" routerLink="/ord">
          <span class="material-icons md-local_grocery_store" title="Ordini" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Ord
          </a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>



      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        
      </form>

      <div class="btn-group" id="ul">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle thumbnail dduser" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/user.png" width="38" height="38">
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/login">Acc</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reg</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dis</a></li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="BasicAuth.isLogged()" routerLink="/logout">Logout {{BasicAuth.loggedUser()}}</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item disabled" *ngIf="!BasicAuth.isLogged()"  href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried to modify the code following the bootstrap one from their site. but nothing doesn't work anyway, i tried to upload my code on stackbitz and it works, but if i start it from my pc it doesn't work.

Comment: After attaching the script in `angular.json` you need to start it manually again. Only saving it won't work.

Comment: Yes I rebooted. I restarted the visual studio program, closed and reopened the terminal. I also restarted the PC but unfortunately nothing changed. It still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same problem 
Solved it by

1. uninstall jquery via npm `npm uninstall jquery` 
   1.1) in angular.json under scripts=[] -> delete the path to jquery
2. In index.html add 
   `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">`
   and also 
   `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
   Those 2 are from bootstrap official [website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)
3. Then I installed popper with `npm install popper.js --save`

This is how it worked for me. Now I when I click on the dropdown button, the dropdown menu opens, but when I click on the button again then it doesn't close.
So, if anybody knows why that happens, let me know. Thanks and I hope it helps

Comment: On production i'd never use CDN, but if this solution works you, you can always download the minified version and link it through angular.json file as script

Comment: @DiegoN. The reasons why one should never use CDN - may it be because of this website https://www.maxlaumeister.com/articles/3-reasons-not-to-use-a-cdn/
Also what minified version do you mean specifically? That one from Bootstrap?

Comment: The one you used though jsdelivr, bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Comment: I fixed it by changing bootstrap version. I installed 5.0.0.